# Typescript, export external object property

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, typescript, amd

I'm using Typescript with RequireJs and I'd like to be able to do

```
import View = require('View');
```

Where `View` is a reference to `Backbone.View`.

1. How do I get typescript to recognize that "View" is an external class such that it can be imported without having to type out the full path? (I currently get the following error: "Unable to resolve external module ''View''").
2. How do I get my module to export Backbone.View? The following errors with "error TS1005: ';' expected".

   ```
   // View.ts 

   /// <reference path="../../typings/backbone/backbone.d.ts" />
   import Backbone = require('backbone');
   export = Backbone.View;
   ```

Comment: I think I have the answer to "2". Changing the last line to `export var View = Backbone.View` seemed to get the error to go away.

Comment: Never mind, that didn't work.  While that error went away, now I get "A class may only extend another class." when I try `class MyView extends View {}`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you will need the relative path to the View.ts file.
Have you tried

```
import View = require('./View')
```

or

```
import View = require('../Views/View')
```

depending on where the View.ts file is located ?

Comment: Yeah, that works but it's a pain to always have to type out the path.  There's gotta be a better way...?

Comment: @uglymunky yes there is a better way : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts/issues/85